# checkout specific branch from remote bare repo [git]

Tags: git, deployment

I have bare repo (as central repo, to exchange with other developers).

Usually to deploy (on dev server) master branch, I login to remote SSH server going to repo root path and run next commands:

```
WWW_ROOT="/path/to/web/root"
GIT_WORK_TREE=$WWW_ROOT 
git checkout -f
```

And it was deployed everytime master branch content. But now I would like to checkout a specific branch.

I tried to change HEAD with `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/specific_branch` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply specify the branch when you checkout:

```
git checkout -f specific_branch
```